# How do you define a value of variable that will be used in two functions when a div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rotation, click

I'm trying to make something where you can either click the arrow buttons to highlight a box and show corresponding text, or you can click the box to show the corresponding text.

I have the arrow buttons working but am not sure how to go about incorporating the ability to click on the box to show the text.

Right now the function for the arrow buttons has a variable called 'now' which is set to 0. This has to get redefined when the box is clicked so that the arrow buttons still work.

```js
var p = $('.text > p');
var rect = $('.rectangles > svg');
var now = 0;

p.hide().first().show();
rect.css("opacity",".3").first().css("opacity","1")

$("#next").click(function (e) {
  p.eq(now).hide();
  rect.eq(now).css("opacity",".3")
  now = (now + 1 < p.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
  p.eq(now).show();
  rect.eq(now).css("opacity","1")
  });

$("#prev").click(function(e) {
  p.eq(now).hide();
  now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : p.length - 1;
  p.eq(now).show();
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

rect:hover {
  fill: black !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#rect1 {
  fill: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#rect2 {
  fill: teal;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#rect3 {
  fill: violet;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
}

#prev, #next {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="prev">&#8249;</a>
<a href="#" id="next">&#8250;</a>

<Br>

<div class="rectangles">
  <svg>
    <rect id="rect1" />
  </svg>

  <svg>
    <rect id="rect2" />
  </svg>

  <svg>
    <rect id="rect3" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="text">
  <p id="text1" class="text">Text 1</p>
  <p id="text2" class="text">Text 2</p>
  <p id="text3" class="text">Text 3</p>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfjyawtd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a click event on `rect` and use `eq()` to get the current index of `rect` and accordingly change its opacity:

```js
var p = $('.text > p');
var rect = $('.rectangles > svg');
var now = 0;

p.hide().first().show();
rect.css("opacity", ".3").first().css("opacity", "1")

$("#next").click(function(e) {
  p.eq(now).hide();
  rect.eq(now).css("opacity", ".3")
  now = (now + 1 < p.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
  p.eq(now).show();
  rect.eq(now).css("opacity", "1")
});

$("#prev").click(function(e) {
  p.eq(now).hide();
  now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : p.length - 1;
  p.eq(now).show();
});

$('rect').on('click', function() {
  rect.css("opacity", ".3")
  rect.eq($(this).index("rect")).css('opacity', '1');
  p.hide();
  p.eq($(this).index("rect")).show();
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

rect:hover {
  fill: black !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#rect1 {
  fill: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#rect2 {
  fill: teal;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#rect3 {
  fill: violet;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
}

#prev,
#next {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="prev">&#8249;</a>
<a href="#" id="next">&#8250;</a>

<Br>

<div class="rectangles">
  <svg>
    <rect id="rect1" />
  </svg>

  <svg>
    <rect id="rect2" />
  </svg>

  <svg>
    <rect id="rect3" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="text">
  <p id="text1" class="text">Text 1</p>
  <p id="text2" class="text">Text 2</p>
  <p id="text3" class="text">Text 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Milan. I noticed after you click on the box, and then click on the arrow, the previous box and text will show. If you click on the arrow a second time things go back to normal. why is this?

Comment: Well, I only added code for click and didn't updated the `now`. Since I am not updating `now`, that's why it isn't going back to normal.

Comment: Noted, thanks for the help!

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jlw88/5w9sfjk6/1/